# Unity gain buffer giving DC out

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, buffer, unity-gain

I am feeding square wave (0-5V) at 1kHz through a [AD713JNZ](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2253286.pdf) op amp which I have wired up as a unity gain buffer, but I'm getting 5V DC on the output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AD713JNZ requires a double-ended power supply.  That means you must power it with +V and -V.  Try powering the -V pin with -5V or switch to a single-ended opamp.

Comment: Any suggestions on a replacement?

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of choices.  How about an LM358?

Comment: The way of supplying ("double-" or "single-ended") does not depend on the op-amp; it is a property of the power supply. Any op-amp can be both single- or double-ended supplied. This is because there is no internal ground in op-amps.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist so why isnt my circuit working if its not a supply issue?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Yes, I know that but I believe you are confusing this issue with the OP.

Comment: @DrBwts, If you want the op-amp to stay in active (linear) mode, you really need an additional negative voltage source (eg, -2 V) and > 5 V positive voltage source.

Comment: @jwh20, I am just saying it as a principle... not for the specific op-amp.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few notable clues in the data sheet that this op-amp will not work from a single rail supply of ground and + 5volts: -

[image]

The graph above tells you that the minimum supply voltage is +/-5 volts or a single rail of ground and +10 volts. Do you see the problem: -

[image]

Then there is the input common mode voltage range: -

[image]

What this is telling you is that if you had a +/- 15 volt power supply, you cannot rely on inputs that approach the negative rail closer than 3.5 volts. Given that your negative rail is 0 volts then it is "illegal" to use an input that can fall below +3.5 volts and, of course, your square wave will unless it is biased properly.

There is a similar story for the output of the op-amp; it cannot be guaranteed to drive down as low as +3 volts and it cannot be guaranteed to drive higher than +2 volts (on a 5 volt supply). Clearly, running on a 5 volt supply is never going to be a good choice with this op-amp because the maximum voltage it can produce is less than the minimum voltage it can produce. Find a rail-to-rail op-amp or use proper supplies.

Answer (score 2):

According to the op amp's datasheet, with +/-15 V supplies (i.e. 30 V between the supply pins) the input common mode range is only

[image]

In other words, your input cannot rise to within about 0.5 V of the positive supply nor fall to within about 3.5 V of the negative supply. Performance is even worse over temperature -- e.g. your input cannot be within 2 V of the positive supply. That is not possible with only 5 V between the positive and negative supply pins.

Similarly, with +/-15 V supplies the output voltage swing is only

[image]

Again, this means that in normal operation the output can only swing to within about 2.1 V of the positive supply and about 2.7 V of the negative supply -- again, not possible with only a 5 V supply.

To use this op amp with an input of 0 V to 5 V you need to set its positive supply to about 7.5 V or more and its negative supply to about -5 V or less (i.e. more negative). Alternatively, you can use the 5 V supply with a different op amp which is designed for rail-to-rail input *and* output, though even then such an op amp will not perform as well so close to its rails (supply voltages) as an op amp with higher supply voltages.